# Script Activity error in Automation Studio

Tags: marketing-cloud, javascript, ampscript, update, automationstudio

I'm trying to run a Script Activity to update specific fields of a Lead in Salesforce (Marketing Cloud connector is already configured and working properly).

Once I click on 'Validate Syntax' it looks well but when I run the Automation it always encounters an error (without description).

The code is:

```
< script runat="server">
Platform.Load('core', '1');
var ampCode = Platform.Function.ContentBlockbyId("150827");
var prog1 = Program.Init(ampCode); 
prog1.Perform();
< /script >
```

The ContentBlockbyId includes the AMPScript with the UpdateSingleSalesforceObject function that selects the LeadID to be updated and there is no error with it.

```
%%[ set @LeadID = "00QXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
set @result = UpdateSingleSalesforceObject('Lead',@LeadID,'MyField','Field_Value')
]%%
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in the AMPScript code:

```
%%[
  set @DemoLead = "00Qxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
  set @Update = UpdateSingleSalesforceObject("Lead",@DemoLead,"field","value")
]%%
%%=v(@Update)=%%
```